# How does the Fibonacci sequence arise in the solution to the CodeChef puzzle Fire and Ice?

Tags: algorithm, math, fibonacci

See https://www.codechef.com/problems/FICE for the original problem statement. The question boils down to counting the number of binary strings of length `n >= 1` where each consecutive run of zeros or of ones has odd length (i.e., the number of strings matching the regexp `(0(00)*|1(11)*)*`).

Why is the solution equal to `2 Fib(n)`, where `Fib` denotes the Fibonacci numbers?

Comment: Better to look at CodeChef blogs. The idea of challenge sites is to solve the problem.

Comment: Oy, this is a practice problem with an editorial already available.

Comment: I am not asking for code, I just want to understand the concept regarding how you guys are able to conclude that this question will get solved by fibonacci series. btw, codes are easily available in the editorials I would have used those codes if I would have wanted to cheat, but I haven't as I want to understand the concept and then try to code it by my self and try to get an AC :)

Comment: Your question requires commenters to research your linked material. All you have given is a question dump.

Comment: @WeatherVane It's not a question dump, since the question is in the title: why is the series to be computed related to the Fibonacci sequence? It's really more of a combinatorics question that belongs on math.SE, though.

Comment: @pravir no don't post the whole problem. If I could solve the question I would post it directly to Code Chef.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's write a recurrence for the answer. Let `T0(n)` be the number of valid strings ending in `0`, and `T1(n)` be the number of valid strings ending in `1`. Since `n >= 1`, the answer is `T0(n) + T1(n)`.

We can find some base cases.

```
T0(1) = 1, since there is one string of length one that ends with 0, i.e., 0
T0(2) = 1, since there is one string of length two that ends with 0, i.e., 10
```

Now let's consider `T0(n)` for `n >= 3`. Given a string of length `n` that ends in `0`, there are two cases, of which exactly one applies. The first case is that the string ends in `10`, in which case dropping the `0` gives a valid string of length `n - 1` ending in `1`. The second case is that the string ends in `000`, in which case dropping the `00` gives a valid string of length `n - 2` ending in `0`.

```
T0(n) = T0(n - 2) + T1(n - 1)
```

We observe by the symmetry of problem that `T0(n) = T1(n)`.

```
T0(n) = T0(n - 2) + T0(n - 1)
```

This is the Fibonacci recurrence. The answer is `T0(n) + T1(n) = 2 Fib(n)`.